# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' [7015]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've taken the code from David Walsh's css animation callback and modified it to TypeScript. However, I'm getting an error and I don't know why:

```
interface IBrowserPrefix {
  [key: string]: string;
}

// http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback
function whichAnimationEvent() {
  let x: keyof IBrowserPrefix;
  const el = document.createElement('temp');
  const browserPrefix: IBrowserPrefix = {
    animation: 'animationend',
    OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
    MozAnimation: 'animationend',
    WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
  };

  for (x in browserPrefix) {
    if (el.style[x] !== undefined) {
    //           ^---- [TS Error]: Element has 'any' type b/c index expression is not of type 'number'
      return browserPrefix[x];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happening because you're attempting to index an object with a numeric index signature with string keys.

`for x in browserPrefix` will give you back a set of keys, which are strings. However for some reason `CSSStyleDeclaration` has its index type set to `number` (and not `string`) - see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17827.

You're getting this error because you have `--noImplicitAny` turned on. A way to get this working (a hacky way) would be to cast the indexer to a string:

```
  for (x in browserPrefix) {
    if (el.style[x as any] !== undefined) {
      return browserPrefix[x];
    }
  }
```

The other way would be to modify the typings (try bumping the issue on github).

while we're here, you should mark `x` with `const` and if you're going to use for-in on an object you should make sure that the property belongs to the object to avoid pulling in anything that is inherited in the prototype chain:

```
  for (const x in browserPrefix) {
    if (browserPrefix.hasOwnProperty(x) && el.style[x as any] !== undefined) {
      return browserPrefix[x];
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, use `for-of` with `Object.keys` instead of `for-in`.

There's no need to define `x` ahead of time here.

Comment: `el.style` is an object, not an array. For example, `document.body.style.color`. OP is referencing it as `document.body.style['color']`, which is valid.

Comment: @CharlesStover yes, it is. However, the TypeScript typings have the index set to a number, not a string - Hence the issue. I forgot to remove the array comment from my post, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Getting this error in a for-of

Comment: Could you reproduce the error in codesandbox.io, @BenRacicot?

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in the code, the first one is that `IBrowserPrefix` is defined as having a string index and thus `keyof IBrowserPrefix;` will actually be string. I would remove the interface and just use `let x: keyof typeof browserPrefix;`

The next problem is the way typescript defined the `CSSStyleDeclaration` interface. It only include standard properties, not vendor specific ones.

You could a type assertion to tell the compiler you know what you are doing and ignore the error

```
export function whichAnimationEvent() {

    const el = document.createElement('temp');
    const browserPrefix = {
        animation: 'animationend',
        OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
        MozAnimation: 'animationend',
        WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
    };
    let x: keyof typeof browserPrefix;
    for (x in browserPrefix) {
        if (el.style[x as keyof CSSStyleDeclaration] !== undefined) {
            return browserPrefix[x];
        }
    }
}
```

You could also extend with `CSSStyleDeclaration` with the vendor specific keys you require.

Answer (score 2):

Try `for (x of Object.keys(browserPrefix))` instead of `for (x in browserPrefix)`.

It's typically frowned upon to use the `in` keyword for a loop, because [you may get properties that do not belong to the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only).